Where to place the link to first page after implementing Pagination?
We implemented Pagination on an ecommerce website but now we see in Google search results "Italian tiles, Page 32" instead of the main (first) page "Italian tiles". We know thaw we must put a link to the first page on all individual ones to make Google understand the first page might be a better landing page than other pages in the collection but we don't know where this link to the first page should be placed. Does anyone have an idea about it?
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/ecommerce/pagination-and-incremental-page-loading#sequentially

In your pagination. I'm not sure how you implemented it, but a classic pagination usually shows first, last and n neighbouring pages.
The graphic on the page you linked also clearly demonstrates how a proper pagination should look:

Page number 1 is visible on all the 3 examples of being on page 1, 5 and 9. I used red circles to distinguish the 1st page.
Also, make sure each page has each own canonical link. One could make it page 32 on all the pages by mistake.

Thanks for your answer. By the way do you know also if the first page should reference to itself?

Yes, it should, as on example 1. Google shows a highlighted number one to show it as active page.

This is not likely a problem that you need to solve. Especially if you're seeing this shortly after implementing the pagination. Crawling and indexing take time - as Google becomes more familiar with your content you should see anomalies like this dissipate.
rel='next' and rel='previous' can be implemented for other search engines, but Google itself does not use them anymore to understand collections.
Here's what you should do to optimize your pagination:
Option 1. - Make sure that each paginated page contains a self-referencing canonical URL
Given https://example.com/dresses/page/2
The following should exist in the markup on that page:
<link rel=canonical href="https://example.com/dresses/page/2">

This is probably best and easiest if your site uses rel='next' and rel='previous' - which you shouldn't get rid of just because Google doesn't use it.
Option 2. - Canonicalize a "View All" page
In this scenario, you have 1 page that contains all of the items in a collection.
https://example.com/dresses/view-all/
There are a variety of methods that you can use to load this content such as lazy loading, AJAX, etc.
What you want in this situation is this:
Given https://example.com/dresses/page/2
The following should exist in the markup on that page:
<link rel=canonical href="https://example.com/dresses/view-all">

Providing a good user experience is essential
You can make the user experience better by ensuring that paginated pages have intuitive title tags and by using breadcrumbs.
A lot of times, a robust taxonomy structure can solve this too. What do I mean?
Let's say that page 56 of your women's dresses page contains a bunch of strapless black dresses.
Without any better options, Google might show this page in the results for relevant queries. The solution is easy:
https://example.com/dresses/black/strap-less
^ This page contains all strapless black dresses
Google will prefer this page over https://example.com/dresses/page/56. Nothing should change as far as canonicals go - both pages should have self-referencing canonicals.
Why does Google show random paginated pages instead of the first page?
Google is going to index the collection based on perceived relevancy.
So if page 56 contains products that it believes are more relevant to the user's query than what's on page 1, then it will show page 56 in the results.
Another way that Google assesses relevancy is through internal links - if page 56 is linked to more frequently than page 1, this is a signal to show page 56 to users more often.
So make sure that your internal linking is intentional, and that there are not any back-end shenanigans going on that unintentionally produce crawlable links.

Regarding my taxonomy example, the URL was not literally what a product variant should look like. It was just for understanding. Something like https://example.com/dresses/strapless?color="black" would be more realistic.
